# C++ std::thread - multithread slower than singlethread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am participating in Advent of Code 2021. At Day 6 there was [THIS PUZZLE](https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/6)

Before coming with proper, fast solution I did recursive function like this:

```
long long unsigned int getOffspring(int daysToEnd){
    static long long unsigned int i = 0;
    while(daysToEnd > 0){
        getOffspring(daysToEnd - 9);
        daysToEnd -= 7;
    }
    i+=1;
    return i;
}
```

Which was called in a loop for every of the 300 entries in the input. For the 2nd part of puzzle (256 days instead 80) that gave me a correct answer but it took 100 minutes to compute ( approx 300 * 20 s per loop iteration).

Then I decided to fiddle around with threads, as I did not have much of experience with them.

My idea was to create as many threads as is possible via `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` in my case it's 12 threads.
I thought that having 12 threads would speed up the total operation approx. 10 times.

But as I started to measure the execution time the application got much slower instead being faster.

The code I wrote (now it has some macros for easier manipulation for data harvest):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>

std::atomic<int> threadsLeft (0);
std::mutex myMtx;
std::mutex totalMtx;
constexpr auto HARDWARE_THREADS = 12;

// std::atomic<long long unsigned int > totalCounter(0); // UNUSED FOR NOW
volatile long long unsigned int totalCounter = 0;
volatile long long unsigned int offsprings[HARDWARE_THREADS] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; //TOTAL COUNTER FOR EACH THREAD (SUPPOSE IT'S UP TO 12)
volatile int fish = 0; 


// MODIFY THESE DEFINES FOR TESTS
#define DAYS 160 //SET TO DAY VALUE

// #define USE_TABLE //SET OR COMMENT FOR DIFFERENT COUNTING
#define USE_MAX_THREADS // SET OR COMMENT FOR DIFFERENT COUNTING
// #define DO_NOT_USE_THREADS // SET OR COMMENT FOR NOT SPAWNING THREAD

void getOffspring(int daysToEnd, const int& threadID = 0){
    
    while(daysToEnd > 0){
        getOffspring(daysToEnd - 9, threadID);
        daysToEnd -= 7;
    }

    #ifdef USE_TABLE
        //AVOID MUTEX
        offsprings[threadID] +=1;
    #else
        totalMtx.lock();
        totalCounter += 1;
        totalMtx.unlock();
    #endif
 }
    
void threadJob(std::list<int> * inputValues, int threadID){
    
    while(1){
        myMtx.lock();
        if (inputValues->size() <= 0){
            myMtx.unlock();
            break;
        }
        int startCntr = inputValues->back();
        inputValues->pop_back();
        myMtx.unlock();
        auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        getOffspring( DAYS - startCntr, threadID); //Switch between 
        myMtx.lock();
        std::cout << "Done in "<< std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count()  << " fish " << fish++ << std::endl;
        myMtx.unlock();
    }
}


int main(){
    auto origin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::string fileName("in6.txt");
    std::fstream file;
    std::string number;
    std::list<int> inputValues;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    file.open(fileName);
    while(!file.eof()){
        std::getline(file,number,',');
        inputValues.push_back(std::stoi(number));
    }

    #ifdef USE_MAX_THREADS
        threadsLeft = std::thread::hardware_concurrency() ;
    #else
        threadsLeft = 1;
    #endif 


    #ifdef DO_NOT_USE_THREADS
        for (auto x : inputValues){
            auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            getOffspring(DAYS - x,0);
            std::cout << "Done in "<< std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count()  << " fish " << fish++ << std::endl;
        }
    #else
        for( int i = 0 ; i < threadsLeft ; ++i){
            threads.emplace_back(std::thread(threadJob,&inputValues,i));        
        }
        for (std::thread & t : threads) {
            t.join();
        }
    #endif

    for(auto x  = 0 ; x < HARDWARE_THREADS ;  ++x ){
        totalCounter += offsprings[x];
    }
    std::cout << "Total value: " << totalCounter << std::endl;
    std::cout << "TotalTime ;"<< std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - origin).count() << "; us " << std::endl;
}
```

After some measurements for 80 days (30 measurements) and 160 days (10 measurements) I got following results of total execution time:

Best total time:

1. 4643.2 us 80 DAYS, COUNT IN TABLE, MAX THREADS
2. 5539.5 us 80 DAYS, COUNT IN TABLE, SINGLE THREAD
3. 5703.8 us 80 DAYS, COUNT IN TABLE, DON’T SPAWN THREAD

Best total time:

1. 1677962.7 us 160 DAYS, COUNT IN TABLE, MAX THREADS
2. 2201221.2 us 160 DAYS, COUNT IN TABLE, DON’T SPAWN THREAD
3. 2454063.0 us 160 DAYS, COUNT IN TABLE, SINGLE THREAD

And worst total time:

1. 32238021.0 us 160 DAYS, COUNT WITH MUTEX, MAX THREADS
2. 8444803.9 us 160 DAYS, COUNT WITH MUTEX, SINGLE THREAD
3. 8329748.3 us 160 DAYS, COUNT IN MUTEX, DON’T SPAWN THREAD

If I understand correctly the mutexes have **HUGE** overhead therefore code execution takes longer.
Am I right?
And finally my most important question:

**WHY USING MORE THREADS SPEEDS UP THIS CODE JUST BY ~25%?**
As I am noob in this multithreading stuff I will be greatful for any input!

Best regards!

Comment: As i see it its probably a small job to spare against 12 threads. Dont forget that every lock you make (and every if statement for unclock etc.) takes 12x time and some threads just remain stall.
To solve this you need a better code structure, and maybe try less threads in beginning as more threads overall produce more overhead.
The else endif segment in  getOffSpring is a poor choice to parallelize as is, just think of the 12 threads waiting to access and lock the variable and then unlock it. If you want to run multithreaded programmes give each thread enough work between locks.

Comment: Your `USE_TABLE` idea is a good one; at the very least , making `totalCounter` atomic would be cheaper than using the mutex.  As another point, `volatile` is never appropriate for this situation: if the variables are protected by proper locking or atomicity then `volatile` is unnecessary, and if they aren't then `volatile` won't save you from UB.  It just inhibits optimization for no gain.

Comment: By the way, under `USE_TABLE` you would not need anything special on the `offsprings` array; every thread only accesses its own element, so there is no data race.  It can be a plain ordinary array, no need for a mutex or atomic or volatile.

Comment: The `USE_TABLE` is good, but also be aware of the risk of [_false sharing_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing). That risk can be mitigated either by (A) make the array elements larger (e.g., make it an array of `struct`s that are padded out to a larger size), or else (B) keep the per-thread counts in local variables while the threads are running, and only publish them to the array just before the threads end.